# summing large number of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large number of pandas dataframes with exact same keys and columns names. They have data as follows:

```
z1.ix[0]
val1        [1, 5, 3, 4]
val2        47
Name: 2017-01-01 01:00:00, dtype: object

z2.ix[0]
val1        [11, 5, 53, 5]
val2        4
Name: 2017-01-01 01:00:00, dtype: object

z3.ix[0]
val1        [1, 25, 3, 4]
val2        7
Name: 2017-01-01 01:00:00, dtype: object
```

I tried the following:

```
summedDf = z1 + z2 + z3
```

which gives the following:

```
summedDf.ix[0]
val1        [1, 5, 3, 4, 11, 5, 53, 5, 1, 25, 3, 4]
val2        58
Name: 2017-01-01 01:00:00, dtype: object
```

I was however hoping to achieve the following instead:

```
summedDf.ix[0]
val1        [13, 35, 59, 13]
val2        58
Name: 2017-01-01 01:00:00, dtype: object
```

Also, how do I scale the above addition to about 500 dataframes?

Edit:
`val1` and `val2` are different column names. `val1` stores list and `val2` stores value for each index.

Comment: I guess you can concatenate into one `df` and then use df.sum along an axis.

Comment: Are those lists stored in a column? Or do the *val2* repeat for each *val1* item? Please show full frame and not slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably not the most efficient, but will get you started:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# gen test data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val1':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'val2': [1,2]})
df1
```

gives,

```
    val1       val2
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [4, 5, 6]   2
```

another dataframe:

```
def check(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        output = [i * 2 for i in x]
    else:
        output = x*2
    return output

df2 = df1.applymap(lambda x: check(x))
df2
```

gives,

```
    val1       val2
0   [2, 4, 6]   2
1   [8, 10, 12] 4
```

adding data frames:

```
def add_cols(df1, df2, col):
    if isinstance(df1[col][0], list):
        df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
        df2[col] = df2[col].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
    return df1[col].add(df2[col])


def add_dfs(df1, df2):
    for c in df1.columns:
        df1.loc[:,c] = add_cols(df1, df2, c)
    return df1


# you can use a generator to read dataframes on the fly
# instead of loading all into a list
dfs = [df1, df2]


for e, df in enumerate(dfs):
    if e == 0:
        df_sum = df.copy()
    else:
        df_sum = add_dfs(df1, df2)
```

gives desired output:

```
    val1          val2
0   [5, 10, 15]     5
1   [20, 25, 30]    10
```